# "Waiting for Debugger" message?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

I am creating a language translator application using the Google API in Android 2.2.

I am getting text from one text box (edit1) and converting it in to another language and setting it into another textbox (edit2) as of following code:

```
 Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
 OutputString = Translate.execute(InputString,Language.ENGLISH, Language.GERMAN);
 edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 edit2.setText(OutputString.toString());
```

But when I execute the program app opens with a message saying

> Application Activities('net.learn2develop.Activities') is waiting for the debugger to attach.[Force Close]

Whereas in the Eclipse console I get these set of messages

> [2011-08-19 11:23:29 - Activities] Attempting to connect debugger to 'net.learn2develop.Activities' on port 8626

Due to this I am not able to run my application because the debugger is never able to attach. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a coding problem, but more like a problem in your dev. environment...

Comment: What do you want to do : run your program or debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>: run your program (the run button)

<kbd>F11</kbd>: debug your program (the debug button). It is the case where you get to wait for the debugger too...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your application using Run As --> Android Application. If it still tells the same, it's better you create a new workspace and try to run it.